# Akka HTTP Error Response entity was not subscribed after 1 second

Tags: http, request, akka, subscribe

I am using Akka HTTP cachedHostConnectionPoolHttps pool to send requests as part of Akka Streams Flow:

```
  private val requestFlow: Flow[(HttpRequest, HelperClass), Either[Error, String], _] =
Http().cachedHostConnectionPoolHttps(BaseUrl).mapAsync(1) {
  case (Success(HttpResponse(_, _, entity, _)), _) =>
    Unmarshal(entity).to[String].map(response => {
      Right(response)
    })
  case (Failure(ex), _) =>
    Future(Left(Error(ex)))
}
```

For some reason not all request responses are being processed. Some results in error:

```
a.h.i.e.c.PoolGateway - [0 (WaitingForResponseEntitySubscription)] Response entity was not subscribed after 1 second. Make sure to read the response entity body or call `discardBytes()` on it.
```

How to subscribe to my response while maintaining the flow above?

Comment: Please refer to akka-http doc https://doc.akka.io/docs/akka-http/current/implications-of-streaming-http-entity.html#integrating-with-akka-streams, it suggests a solution for this exact issue.

Comment: I read the documentation and updated my solution accordingly, but I still somehow miss the entity

Comment: Ok, my problem may come from some multithreaded events happening earlier in the flow. In unit test provided solution worked and errors don't occur anymore

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As suggested in docs, implementing entity handling the following way solves the issue:

```
          private val requestFlow: Flow[(HttpRequest, HelperClass), Either[Error, String], _] =
Http().cachedHostConnectionPoolHttps(BaseUrl).mapAsync(1) {
  case (Success(HttpResponse(_, _, entity, _)),    _) =>
      entity.dataBytes
        .runReduce(_ ++ _)
        .map(r => Right(r.toString))
  case (Failure(ex), _) =>
    Future(Left(Error(ex)))
}
```

Answer (score 4):

Although it's not the best solution, you can increase the response subscription timeout like this:

```
akka.http.host-connection-pool.response-entity-subscription-timeout = 10.seconds
```

Here is a more thorough discussion: https://github.com/akka/akka-http/issues/1836