# Akka-http Response entity was not subscribed after 5 minutes

Tags: scala, akka-stream, akka-http

I have an akka-streams application, and there is a graph which includes a bunch of http calls.
It works perfect for a while (10-20 minutes), and after some time fails with the next reason:

```
[LoaderActorSystem-akka.actor.default-dispatcher-54] [LoaderActorSystem/Pool(shared->https://chpp.hattrick.org:443)] [3 (WaitingForResponseEntitySubscription)]Response entity was not subscribed after 5 minutes. Make sure to read the response `entity` body or call `entity.discardBytes()` on it -- in case you deal with `HttpResponse`, use the shortcut `response.discardEntityBytes()`. GET /chppxml.ashx Empty -> 200 OK Default(18198 bytes)
```

As recommended [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62053942/akka-http-error-response-entity-was-not-subscribed-after-1-second) and at the [documentation](https://doc.akka.io/docs/akka-http/current/implications-of-streaming-http-entity.html#integrating-with-akka-streams) I've implemented parsing of the requests next way:

```scala
    val httpsFlow = Http().cachedHostConnectionPoolHttps[T](URL)

    val unmarshallFlow = Flow[(Try[HttpResponse], T)].mapAsync(2){
      case (Success(response), t) =>
        response.entity.dataBytes
          .runReduce(_ ++ _)
          .map(data => (data.utf8String, t))
    }
      .map(parse)

    httpsFlow.via(unmarshallFlow).async
```

So, before this error my app performs thousands of http calls, I can't find the reason why the problems appear.

Subscription timeout config is 5 minutes(changed it from 10 seconds to 1 hour, it doesn't help):

```
akka.http.host-connection-pool.response-entity-subscription-timeout = 5.minute
```

Comment: What is the result without `.async` at the end? Does it behave the same way?

Comment: Yes, without `async` it behaves the same way

Comment: Do you have any other related errors? Can you try to handle the failure case as well and retry?

Comment: No, I have no other related errors. Also I was trying to handle errors explicitly `case (Failure(_), t) => Future(("", t))`, It give the same result

Comment: In case of failure you should call `response.entity.discardEntityBytes()`

Comment: How can I do this? In case of Failure I have only `Failure(throwable)`, and no `response`.

Comment: You are right, ignore my previous comment. As I see you want to extract String from the response entity. It would be better to use `Unmarshal(result.entity).to[String]` in that case.

Comment: @bmateusz, changed to `Unmarshal(result.entity).to[String]` and still getting the same errors..